# Java - Means for detecting circular reference in MVC-patterned application

Tags: java, circular-dependency, circular-reference

During my instrumentation, I had some issues with replacing a class definition in JVM. The modification of the class met all constraints (e.g. method addition, change of signature, static variable addition/modification etc.). But the only thing I couldn't check, and which stands out, is the circular reference.

The class I am handling is quite large and part of typical MVC-patterned action class from struts X.X. Is there any way I can use some existing library/open source tool which can help me identify circular reference?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can check the dependencies through `metricsreloaded`. It's a plugin which has some other functionalities as well like calculating `cyclometic complexity` etc.

You haven't mentioned the IDE you are using. In `IntelliJ` you can install that plugin either from here [MetricsReloaded](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/93-metricsreloaded) or through plugin store(by searching metricsreloaded).

There must be a plugin for `eclipse` as well.

Alternatively you can install `SonarLint` plugin as well from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7973-sonarlint) which also provides this functionality.

For `Eclipse` try [SonarLint](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sonarlint)

Comment: Are you referring to Eclipse Metrics http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=90 ?

Comment: @ha9u63ar if the above is not available you can try `SonarLint` for eclipse from here https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sonarlint

Comment: @ha9u63ar have added on the last line.